# Batch Script task getting cancelled because of mysterious input

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have defined a Batch Script task in my Azure DevOps pipeline.  I can see from the logs that it starts and runs the first few commands in the bat file, but then all of a sudden I see "Cancelled" in the log and the task finishes as a successful task.

My bat file runs a custom executable that allows cancelling mid way through if it detects any input from the console.  This is what appears to be happening when the bat is run by the pipeline.

Why would the pipeline be entering input into the console window while the bat is still executing, and how do I get it to stop?

Batch Script Task Output:
Press Enter to stop
Running executable
Cancelled
executable finished with error code: -1

Comment: I'd change your script to echo out the input before exiting, then it will appear in the logs. Could give you / us more clues on what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I'm not even sure AzureDevOps was really entering input into the Console the ways I thought it was.  What I did ultimately discover, though, is that when a console app is run by AzureDevOps, it redirects all input, which prevents the console app from capturing the input for direction.  I ended up using this code to skip my logic that was looking for a "quit" operator when input is re-directed.

```
        if (Environment.UserInteractive && !Console.IsInputRedirected)
        {
            // if don't test for UserInteractive, will run into issues when run by DevOps pipeline.
            // DevOps pipeline causes IsInputRedirected to be true, which results in this exception.
            // Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.                     

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop");
            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadKey();
                if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    // quit once enter is entered
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // if console does not allow user input, just wait until the task is cancelled
            ct.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
```